# how to enlarge the gui or increase font size when launching qemu

Tags: virtualbox, qemu

I run qemu on ubuntu, which is running in virtualbox of MacBook pro. The size of qemu's font is too small or the gui is too small. How to enlarge the qemu gui or increase the font size of qemu. Below is my system's snapshot.

[image]

Comment: I use -vga virtio on the qemu command line from a terminal.  That allows resizing (and therefore the font appears larger).

Comment: It shows "Unknown vga type: virtio" in terminal when using "-vga virtio"

Comment: My terminal command is: kvm -smp cpus=2,threads=2 -cpu host -m 4096 -vga virtio -usb $IMAGE   I added the virtio when I decided the window was too small, then I could resize it larger.